# Simultaneously Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I have two diagonalisable matrices $M$ and $N$ and would like to show that the eigenvalues (in order) of $M$ are greater than those of $N$. Now, $M-N$ has only non-negative eigenvalues, so if the two were symmetric I would be done. I know how to make each symmetric with respect to a particular basis, but unfortunately, when I do so to each independently, their difference has negative eigenvalues. So I was wondering when it would be possible so *simultaneously* make $M$ and $N$ symmetric, i.e., choose a basis with respect to which both are symmetric, which would easily carry through to their difference, proving the result.